# Line for x axis and make y-axis names straight

Tags: r

I am new to R. I have this bar chart. I have to add a line to the bottom part (For x-axis). I also have to make the numbers (0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100) straight. I share my code with you. I appreciate for any advise. Thank you.

```
number.concentration1 <-c(90,90,90,90,90,100,90,100,90,100)
number.concentration2<-c(100,100,100,100,100,80,100,100,70,100)
number.concentration3<-c(100,90,80,90,90,70,10,50,40,0)
number.concentration4<-c(30,30,10,0,0,20,30,0,30,30)
number.concentration5<-c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
n<-10
a<-5
treatment <- data.frame(Number=c(number.concentration1, number.concentration2, number.concentration3, number.concentration4, number.concentration5),Concentration=rep(c("Control","0.1 ppm","1 ppm","10 ppm","100 ppm"), each=n))
treatment
treatment $Concentration <- factor(treatment$Concentration, levels(treatment$Concentration)[c(5,1,2,3,4)])
aov.out1 <- aov(Number ~ Concentration, data= treatment)
summary(aov.out1)
TukeyHSD(aov.out1)
model.tables(aov.out1, type="means", se=TRUE)
ybar.<-mean(treatment$Number)
ybar.
ybar.i <- tapply(treatment$Number, treatment$Concentration, mean)
ybar.i 
SSa<-n*sum((ybar.i-ybar.)^2)
SSa
y.ij <- treatment$Number
SSw <- sum((y.ij - rep(ybar.i, each=n))^2)
SSw
df1<-a-1
MSa<-SSa/df1
MSa
df2<-a*(n-1)
MSw<-SSw/df2
MSw
F.stat<-MSa/MSw
F.stat
F.crit<-qf(0.95,df1,df2)
F.crit
p.value<-1-pf(F.stat,df1,df2)
p.value

xx<-barplot(ybar.i,ylim=c(0,103),xlab="Concentrations",cex.lab=1.5,ylab="Pupae formation percentages")
mean.SE<-7.994
arrows(xx,ybar.i,xx,ybar.i+mean.SE,angle=90,length=0.05)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the abline function in R [abline](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/abline-r-function-an-easy-way-to-add-straight-lines-to-a-plot-using-r-software)

abline(h=0), a horizontal line at x = 0

```
#R version 3.3.2 

number.concentration1 <-c(90,90,90,90,90,100,90,100,90,100)
number.concentration2<-c(100,100,100,100,100,80,100,100,70,100)
number.concentration3<-c(100,90,80,90,90,70,10,50,40,0)
number.concentration4<-c(30,30,10,0,0,20,30,0,30,30)
number.concentration5<-c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
n<-10
a<-5
treatment <- data.frame(Number=c(number.concentration1, number.concentration2, number.concentration3, number.concentration4, number.concentration5),Concentration=rep(c("Control","0.1 ppm","1 ppm","10 ppm","100 ppm"), each=n))
treatment
treatment $Concentration <- factor(treatment$Concentration, levels(treatment$Concentration)[c(5,1,2,3,4)])
aov.out1 <- aov(Number ~ Concentration, data= treatment)
summary(aov.out1)
TukeyHSD(aov.out1)
model.tables(aov.out1, type="means", se=TRUE)
ybar.<-mean(treatment$Number)
ybar.
ybar.i <- tapply(treatment$Number, treatment$Concentration, mean)
ybar.i 
SSa<-n*sum((ybar.i-ybar.)^2)
SSa
y.ij <- treatment$Number
SSw <- sum((y.ij - rep(ybar.i, each=n))^2)
SSw
df1<-a-1
MSa<-SSa/df1
MSa
df2<-a*(n-1)
MSw<-SSw/df2
MSw
F.stat<-MSa/MSw
F.stat
F.crit<-qf(0.95,df1,df2)
F.crit
p.value<-1-pf(F.stat,df1,df2)
p.value

xx<-barplot(ybar.i,ylim=c(0,103),xlab="Concentrations",cex.lab=1.5,ylab="Pupae formation percentages")
abline(h=0) #Abline function
mean.SE<-7.994
arrows(xx,ybar.i,xx,ybar.i+mean.SE,angle=90,length=0.05)
```